# Регулярное выражение для обращения только к существующим файлам

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

На сервере стоит nginx с конфигом:

```
server {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location / {
        ...
        location ~* ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
          ...
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

Любые невалидные ссылки, содержащие расширение *.php*, например от типичных сканеров, постоянно наблюдаемых на сайте:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
 .../forumdisplay.php/newthread.php (No such file or directory)"

FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
 .../forumdisplay.php/register.php (No such file or directory)"

FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
 .../wp-content/plugins/wpshop/includes/ajax.php (No such file or directory)"
```

Пролетают в *бэкэнд*.

Но поставить на входе *php-локации*

```
try_files   $uri  = 404;
```

не могу, т.к. перестаёт работать форум, где типичны ссылки вида:

```
site.ru/thread.php/946-Название_темы?p=186095#post196005
site.ru/search.php?do=getnew&contenttype=type1
```

и.т.п.

Как всё корректно настроить?

Comment: *пролетают в бэкэнд* — а что, в корне сайта нет файла `register.php`?

Comment: впрочем, если бы сработала директива `try_files`, то *url* выглядел бы как `/index.php?ещё-что-нибудь`. так у вас проблема с составлением регулярного выражения, находящего две подстроки `.php` в запросе?

Comment: Сначала я думал что да, но проблема шире. Если двойное расширение можно побороть саблокацией `location ~* ^(.*\.php.*\.php.*)` , то все остальные невалидные скрипты все равно попадают в бэкэнд. ( подредактировал вопрос)

Comment: так добавьте и «все остальные невалидные». или выработайте критерий, по которому можно определить валидность/невалидность.

Comment: В невалидные попадают любые несуществующие файлы php, это не отфильтруешь. А если ставлю try_files на входе php локации, каким-то образом срабатывает try_files в корневой локации и по любым валидным ЧПУ ссылкам идет редирект в корень...

Comment: в `try_files` нельзя использовать регулярные выражения. максимум — псевдо-переменные `$1`, `$2` и т.д., соответствующие тому, что попало в скобки внутри регулярного выражения директивы `location`, внутри которой и находится этот `try_files`. но для вашего случая это, насколько я понимаю, бесполезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте вставить такую директиву `try_files` в самый внутренний `location`:

```
location ~* ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
  try_files $1 =404; # вот эту
  ...
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

она проверит существование файла, имя которого совпало с первой из групп регулярного выражения директивы `location`. с этой вот группой: `(.+?\.php)`

если файл не существует, директива возвратит 404-ю ошибку.

если существует, `nginx` выполнит остальные директивы в этом `location`-е.

Comment: Это именно то, что я искал.  Все побочные проблемы решаются автоматически саблокациями.